# Starting a socket on a settings page and allowing the MainPage to access it WP8

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8

I have class that the MainPage of my app can access, but it requires  user input for the ip address so I've setup a new page rather like a settings page, if I add the same code as the MainPage the socket works as expected but I only want to send  the connect command from the settings page then allow the MainPage to send the values to the socket... if I connect on settings page and then try to send data from MainPage I get "Socket not initialized" when it was as it was done from the Settings Page, can anybody explain whats happening here and possible solutions? it's like the app page is two different 'ecosystems' and the two can't combine methods and vars etc?

Am I looking into this wrong and yes you've guessed it I'm hopelessly new to all this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page in a WP app is a separate class.  So where is your Socket object declared?  If you declared it as an instance variable of the MainPage class (for example), it would not be in scope when the Settings page is active (or vice versa).

To allow both pages to reference the same instance of Socket, you can declare it as a public member in App class.  And you'll probably want to declare it static as is done with App.RootFrame in the automagically generated app templates, to make it easy to reference.

Comment: the socket code is in itself a class and you send the connect code to it I guess you mean I could move the connect and read parts to a separate class file and reference it there yes?

Comment: I think the issue is with this line SocketClient client = new SocketClient(); that's needed on every page but it can't be so I assume like I said if I moved that bit of code to a seperate class then it would only get read once per connect and fix the issue?